# Read file text and store in array 2d

Tags: lua

I have a file text "a.txt" :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Now i want store it in array 2d :

array ={ {1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9} }
I have try to :

```
array ={}
file = io.open("a.txt","r")
io.input(file)
i=0
for line in io.lines() do
   array[i]=line
   i=i+1
end
```

But it doesn't success.
Does anyone suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some errors in your code. You first open the file `a.txt` and then set it for standard input. You don't need the open(). But i recommend to open the file and operate on it, using the `lines()` iterator on the file:

```
array = {}
file = io.open("a.txt","r")
i = 0
for line in file:lines() do
   array[i]=line
   i=i+1
end
```

Furthermore, with your method, you don't get the array you wished for (`{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} }`) but instead an array containing strings as elements:
`{ "1 2 3", "4 5 6", "7 8 9" }`.
To get the latter, you have to parse the string you have read. An easy way to do this is to use `string.match` with captures:

```
array ={}
file = io.open("a.txt","r")
for line in file:lines() do
    -- extract exactly three integers:
    local t = { string.match(line, "(%d+) (%d+) (%d+)")) }
    table.insert(array, t) -- append row
end
```

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match. For a arbitrary number of integers (or other numbers) on every line, you can use a loop together with string.gmatch():

```
array ={}
file = io.open("a.txt","r")
for line in file:lines() do
    local t = {} 
    for num in string.gmatch(line, "(%d+)") do
        table.insert(t, num)
    end
    table.insert(array, t)
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what i looking for . Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! If you like my answer, be kind and accept it :)

Comment: You can use `for line in io.lines("a.txt") do`.